# Where are Diagnostic Logging Categories stored?

Tags: diagnostics

I am looking for the location where SharePoint 2010 stores Diagnostic Logging Categories located on the Central Administration Diagnostic Logging page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not simply a file or list somewhere. The Diagnostic areas and sub-categories are provided by custom diagnostic services derived from the SPDiagnosticsServiceBase.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am following this article but want to know where the data is stored for the categories specified in the enum.  In my case I continue to have problems with duplicate categories being created and was hoping to locate where they are being store to be sure they don't previously exist because of development deploys and redeploys.

Comment: I can guess that duplicate entries were created because two different custom service (assuming sharepoint would not allow same service to be provisioned more than once) provisioned same category name. If you look into the article below, when a feature is deactivated, the service is deleted. You may have to write similar code (a console app or powershell) to delete the service.

Comment: I see references to my old classes in the Farm's content database in the Classes table.  What is best way to clear them out?  My Central Admin shows no references to the solution in the Solution Management Page.

Comment: There appears to be references to class objects created by my Farm Solution in Classes and Objects tables of the farm configuration db .  My test show that Remove-SPSolution cmdlet does not remove the records from these tables.  Although not supported by MS I deleted the records of my orphaned classes and my problems were solved.

Comment: Blogged about this http://tjo.me/kC5hMj

Comment: @ChiliYago your answer helped,  it should be posted as answer

Answer (score 1):

Looking at steps required to create Custom Logging Service and registering with SharePoint, it can be fairly said that that information is coming from SharePoint farm's configuration database. But the point is, you can have more categories added there and below are the links to get started:

http://jbaurle.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/how-to-implement-a-custom-sharepoint-2010-logging-service-for-uls-and-windows-event-log/

and..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservicebase.aspx